# Orthogonal Complement Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone help me or give me a hint on the following problem?

> Let $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Let $M := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax = b\}$ and assume $M$ to be nonempty. Show that there is $x_0 \perp \operatorname{Ker}(A)$ such that $(M^\perp)^\perp = \operatorname{Span}(x_0) + \operatorname{Ker}(A)$

where $x_0$ is a single vector.

Comment: Maybe you can throw some mathematical typesetting on this and tell us how you attacked the problem so far!

Comment: sorry I'm new here dont know how to type the problem correctly !

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Looks like you bothered no more to look at this tutorial as you bothered to put some initial effort in the problem.